# How to add a gradient to the navbar in bootstrap 3 using LESS.js

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, gradient

ie looks like: http://twitterbootstrap3navbars.w3masters.nl/ but without using raw css, I want to write this into my less files...

In my less.variables I already tried this:

```
@navbar-gradient:   linear-gradient(top, @navbar-default-pre-color 0%, @navbar-default-pre-color 50%, @navbar-default-pre-color 51%, @navbar-default-pre-color 100%);

@navbar-default-bg:                @navbar-gradient;
```

In chrome the navbar just showed up black, I tried changeing it from background color to: just background, background-image etc (in the chrome developer tools that let you edit the css right on the page).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using the following Less code:

```
@navbar-gradient-start-color: #004400;
@navbar-gradient-stop-color: #009900;
.navbar-default {
#gradient > .vertical( @navbar-gradient-start-color,@navbar-gradient-stop-color);
}
```

You should add this code at the end of the bootstrap.less (or navnbar.less) file. (better create a custom.less file and import that at the end of bootstrap.less)

Also see: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/adding-background-gradient-bootstraps-navbar-less/

The Less code above will output the following CSS code:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #004400 0%, #009900 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #004400 0%, #009900 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004400 0%, #009900 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff004400', endColorstr='#ff009900', GradientType=0);
}
```

Notice that the .vertical() mixin has been defined in the less/mixins/gradients.less file of Bootstrap's source files. This mixin has been [namespaced](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-and-accessors) in the `#gradient` namespace and that's why it should be called as `#gradient > .vertical()`.

Answer (score 1):

so here's what I rigged up. I added the following at line 380 in navbar.less, under the navbar default class

```
background-color: @navbar-default-bg;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 0%, left 100%, from(lighten(@navbar-default-bg,30%)), to(@navbar-default-bg));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, lighten(@navbar-default-bg,30%), 0%, @navbar-default-bg, 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, lighten(@navbar-default-bg,30%) 0%, @navbar-default-bg 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, lighten(@navbar-default-bg,30%) 0%, @navbar-default-bg 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=lighten(@navbar-default-bg,30%), endColorstr=@navbar-default-bg, GradientType=0);
```

I cut and past some of it from here:  http://twitterbootstrap3navbars.w3masters.nl/

Comment: There is no need to add it at line 380 when you set the above code for the `.navbar` (or .navbar-default) selector you can add it at the end of `bootstrap.less` or `navbar.less` (you should only make sure that the custom code is after the default code, and even that is not required cause of the default code does not set the `background-image` for the navbar)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `@navbar-default-bg` is set to `background-color` and as @StrikePricer pointed out, a gradient needs to be set as `background-image`.

Also it appears you're using the same color at all stops.  So that might be why you're not seeing the gradient.

So a more complete answer (ignoring browser-prefixed fallbacks) would be:

```
// defined in variables.css:
@navbar-gradient-start-color: #004400;
@navbar-gradient-stop-color: #009900;
@navbar-gradient: linear-gradient(to bottom, @navbar-gradient-start-color 0%, @navbar-gradient-stop-color 100%);

// in your main definitions/ overrides:
.navbar {
  background-image: @navbar-gradient; 
}
```

Comment: When you ignore  browser-prefixed fallbacks your answer does not differ from that already given by @StrikePricer already. When using Bootstrap default build process, the autoprfixer should not add the `filter` property for IE8 support.

Comment: Actually my answer differs in at least one important way which is i explained *why* it works.